# Universal Links: continueUserActivity not working when app is not in background

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-universal-links

I manage to do universal links and able to redirect it from continueUserActivity but the problem now is continueUserActivity will not work if the app is not in background. which means if you close the app and click the link it won't open.

I have found a code, but i don't know how to get the url. here is the solution

```
let activityDic = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey]

if let isActivityDic = activityDic {

    // Continue activity here

}
```

because when i check the type data of `isActivityDic` , it's an any object data. please help me to get the url

and this code also throw error

```
if let activityDic = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey] {

        let options = activityDic.allValues.filter({ (option:AnyObject) -> Bool in

            return option is NSUserActivity
        })

        if options.count > 0 , let userActivity = options[0] as? NSUserActivity{
            // User activity handling should be done here 

        }

    }
```